# Kotlin: JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY on data class

Tags: jackson, kotlin, jackson-databind

I want to archive something like this:

```
data class Task(
  @JsonProperty("id", access = READ_ONLY)
  val id: String?

  ...
  <other params>
  ...
)
```

Unfortunately, this results in following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for Task, annotations: [null]] 
has no property name annotation;
must have name when multiple-parameter constructor annotated as Creator
at [Source: {"id":"AT-5", ...}; line: 1, column: 1]

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:305)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:268)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:476)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3899)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3794)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2842)
```

This one works:

```
data class Task(
  @JsonProperty("id")
  val id: String?
)
```

I've tried `@field:JsonProperty` to no avail.

How to get this annotation working in Kotlin?
I use dropwizard 1.1.0,  Jackson 2.8.6

Comment: Hey, it seems to be issue witj Jackson. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/935 it is no closed.

Comment: It is not a bug, you should be using the Jackson-Kotlin module which is designed to prevent this type of issue when using Kotlin with Jackson, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Jackson-Kotlin module and then you will not need to set a `JsonParameter` for each parameter, since the module will infer the other parameter names from what metadata the Kotlin compiler stores in the class.

The module is located in Github at [FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin)

Be sure to follow the instructions to register the module, include the `kotlin-reflect` dependency in your own build, and use the helper functions to simplify your Kotlin code.